# Nesting of layout tag in Magento xml

Tags: magento

I am not sure where to keep my layout xml in the custom module. Does it go in the config.xml of the module or a separate layout.xml is needed. How does Magento picks up the layout xml?

Right now I am using it like this, which doesn't work. A bit clueless here, any pointers? Code samples work great for me :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ashfame_Adminoverrider>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Ashfame_Adminoverrider>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <layout>
            <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
                <reference name="root">
                    <reference name="form">
                        <reference name="data">
                            <block type="ashfame_adminoverrider/sales_order_create_shipping_address" as="shipping_address" template="ashfame/adminoverrider/sales/order/create/form/address.phtml" />
                        </reference>
                    </reference>
                </reference>
            </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
        </layout>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

Config XML and layout XML are two different things.

The `config.xml` files can be used to tell Magento to load a new layout xml file.  Search for `catalog.xml` in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
```

for the correct place to put the nodes in your own XML files.  You're looking for something like this

```
            <catalog>
                <file>catalog.xml</file>
            </catalog>
            <map>
                <file>catalog_msrp.xml</file>
            </map>
```

One you're there, place your globally uniquely named xml file in the base design package's layout folder and/or your theme's layout folder.

That should be enough to get you googling.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Alan! Your book is hard for beginners, BTW. Gonna visit it once I am well versed with everything because I know the book is rock solid. I am yet to try completing the task mentioned here in Q, will post back if I have any questions.

Comment: @Ashfame I'm a little confused by that comment.  My intent was for No Frills Magento Layout to be aimed directly at the Magento beginner.  What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: I actually get lost when you switch from one aspect to another. Like in 1 chapter only, I found myself clueless, and that being said when I don't have any previous experience with MVC or Zend but good 3 years of WordPress experience. You seem to jump too quick and would lost me on keeping myself along you.

Comment: @Ashfame Ah, got it.  I can see how it could be dizzying if this is your first exposure to MVC.  I put the layout code in controller actions because that's the simplest way to run code in Magento.  If you can, just install the extensions that come with the book, edit the files you're told to and load the URLs you're told to. Treat the MVC as black box and focus on the layout/block code.  (Also, reading http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world will help with MVC basics)

Comment: Yep I am very much versed with MVC and EAV now but still find it a bit hard to follow. May be its just me but I thought I would let you know. Great work for the community btw :)

Comment: @ashfame If you wouldn't mind, could you email me (http://www.pulsestorm.net/contact-us/) a more detailed example of the problem's you're having? It runs counter to most people's experience, and it points to me missing a market/mindset I could better serve.

Comment: Sure Alan, I will make sure I send you a detailed example when I get a chance, running hell busy right now.